# working with Xcode and version control tool

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I'm currently working with a few other developers under Xcode environment that is stored in common remote git repository.

Unlike other project editors such as SlickEditor, Xcode is a full development environment, so the project files should also be kept version control, since they bind the compiling information inside (on other cases, we have the compilation info stored in Makefiles, separated from project structure info that can be kept local.)

The problem arise when merges are needed in the project files. since this files are auto generated and can be modified properly only through Xcode UI, it require manual addition rather then merge (simply add the modification of the project files from the source merge, manually from Xcode UI in target).

my question is whether this approach is inevitable, and if there are more efficient, easier ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem arise when merges are needed in the project files. since this files are auto generated and can be modified properly only through Xcode UI

I would advise you not to store auto generated files under version control with Git, or any other VCS.  You should only be versioning your source code.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply, and I totally agree with you. The problem in Xcode is that the auto generated project files also contain the Makefile information inside. so when adding a new file to the project I must "tell" other clients about how to compile this file inside the project, and this can be done only through the project files - so i must add them to VC too.

Comment: Unless there is a tool which can help with this, I'm afraid you will have to manage this by hand.  Suppose two engineers add an Objective C file.  Then whoever commits last will have a merge conflict.  I will delete this answer once someone else posts a better one.